# RPI zero g_mass_storage using a directory

Tags: pi-zero-w, samba, modules

I am trying to use ad rpi zero to access a samba share present on my network so that I can access it to the tv.

I'll try to make it more clear: SMB server --> wifi --> rpi zero --> tv

I have read multiple guides on how to use rpi zero as a removable device but they never mention how to use a whole folder (mounted SMB share on the rpi zero) as the folder accessible from the tv, they always use a .img file that is mounted and recognized by the tv.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What is your connection between the TV and the Pi? USB? HDMI? Ethernet?

Comment: It is USB...........